# How to store predicates permanently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, aiml

When I’m chatting with my bot, it temporarily stores predicates about me in a session file, so that, for the current session, it knows my name, gender, age, etc, whatever comes up about me in that session.  So question #1 would be: Is my understanding correct?

If so, where is that session data stored?

I want to put in persistent sessions, so that when I identify myself, the bot loads the predicates associated with me.  If someone can help me figure out how to do that, or at least how AIML temporarily stores that info, I’m pretty sure I can capture that info and save it in a file that get’s loaded each time.  From there it’s pretty trivial to have files for other users so the chat experience is a bit more personalized, ie: once the bot knows who you are it can retrieve the info it previously knew about you.

In the PyAIML docs there is a very brief discussion about persistent sessions, but I can’t seem to get it to work and I think it’s because I’m not asking it to retrieve the proper info.  I’ve contacted Cort, and he’s been wonderful, but he has moved on to other things and doesn’t remember much about this project.  He’s also a very busy guy with work and a new family and such, and I figured maybe someone here could help me figure it out as I don’t want to “overstay my welcome” as it were with him.

Any suggestions/ guidance?

Comment: "where is that session data stored" - it's stored where you stored it. You've told us you used a "session file", so it's in that file.

Comment: Upon restart,it forgets all the predicates.I want to make those predicates permanent